What is the process for scrubbing personal information on electronics.se?
Recently I decided that I no longer wanted as much personal information to be public on the Internet, so I used the self-service deletion process to remove it. I was met with the following response and a 30-day network-wide ban:

Hello,
We're writing in reference to your Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange account: [link omitted]
You have recently removed many comments indiscriminately from the site, which amounts to vandalism. Therefore we are suspending your account. The suspension duration shown below could be reduced or increased depending on our investigation, but we have to do something now to protect the site.
You have contributed 423 answers and 7 questions to the site so far, thank you for that. It's a shame things have come to this point. Looking at your profile, it seems your dissatisfaction is with Stack Exchange overall and not specifically with the Electrical Engineering site. In that case, it's unlikely we can do anything locally to make any difference. However if you have a concern with something which is specific to this site, you can give feedback by replying to this message.
Your account has been temporarily suspended for 30 days. While you’re suspended, your reputation will show as 1 but will be restored once the suspension ends.
Regards,
Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange Moderation Team

Which process should I use instead to delete all personal information associated with my account, including questions, answers and comments, as permitted under GDPR?

Criticize SE actions means ban - You said that you "used the self-service deletion process to remove it". Which self-service deletion process do you mean? And what is the "it" in that sentence - what did you remove using that process (whichever process that was)? || Just FYI the 30-day site suspension mentioned in the message you quoted, is not the 30-day network suspension you mentioned (as an aside it's not a ban, that's something different).

The proper route is to talk to a community manager. The way you do this is by going to the bottom of the page and finding the contact link.
After that contact support and select the other account issue option then select I need to delete my account:

They will be able to help you with the legal ramifications of deletion. Also answers and questions here are also released under a cc license, so they might not be deletable.

Would that be the same community moderator who banned me for it?

No, that would be a moderator CM's are different. They handle legal issues and work for SE.
